# Mysql union all order by issue when no column I can force order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that is just digits in three different columns.
I am checking the sum of the each row and based on the total value outputting a string and the structure of the query is like:

```
select statement one as string1
union all 
select statement two as string2
and so on...
```

The problem I get is that I want the output to be in the original order row by row, so it would be like:

```
string1
string3
string1
string2 and so on
```

What I get is:

```
string1
string1
string1
string1 
string2
string2

and so on...
```

How to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0 you can use the `row_number` function to produce a running number to order on. In addition, you can add a hard-coded value to differentiate between the columns the value comes from and then order on both:

```sql
SELECT col1 AS col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS rn, 1 AS ind FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT col2 AS col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS rn, 2 AS ind FROM mytable
ORDER BY rn, ind
```

**[DBFiddle sample](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qC2LLAEmCGbFJXvQxgdRpM/0)**

Comment: Hi,
This does not seem to solve the problem unfortunately.  When I use row_number in each select statement these select statements have their own numeration.

So I still end up with the same order but now with numeration like
string1 1 
String1 2 
String2 1 
String2 2 

Instead of

string1 1
string3 2
string1 3
string2 4